# How to iterate nth positions in nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary with unfixed length.

```
[{'name': 'stack', 'children': [{'name': 'flow', 'children': [{'name': 'lldp', 'children': [{'name': 'sourc', 'children': [{'name': 'lldque.jrc', 'count': '11', 'size': '37'}]}]}, {'name': 'arp', 'children': [{'name': 'src', 'children': [{'name': 'arpred.cec', 'count': '37', 'size': '67'}]}]}]}]}]
```

I want to access last dict keys('count' and 'size') from dict.

I have tried below function but it is not working fine.

```
def get_value(your_dict,*keys):
    curr_dict = your_dict
    for k in keys:
        v = curr_dict.get(k,None)
        if v is None:
            break
        if isinstance(v,dict):
            curr_dict = v
    return v
```

Comment: What you have posted is a `list`. I guess you are referring to `your_list[0]` as `your_dict`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general implementation that recursively scans your structure and if it is a `dict` it

```
def find_key_in_nested(struct, key, result_list):
    # Check if it is a list and loop over all elements
    if type(struct) == list:
        for it in struct:
            element = find_key_in_nested(it, key, result_list)
            if element:
                result_list.append(element)
    # Check if it is a dict
    if type(struct) == dict:
        if key in struct.keys(): # It has the required key! Append
            return result_list.append(struct[key])
        # It doesn't have it, keep looking further down
        for k in struct.keys(): 
            element = find_key_in_nested(struct[k], key, result_list)
            if element:
                result_list.append(element)
```

It appends the results in a `list` so you can call it like

```
my_list = []
find_key_in_nested(my_dict, 'size', my_list)
print(my_list)

output:
['37', '67']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively get all of them:

```
from itertools import chain
def get_value(your_dict,*keys):
    if "children" in your_dict:
        return tuple(
          chain.from_iterable(
            get_value(d, *keys) for d in your_dict["children"]
            )
        )
    return tuple(your_dict[k] for k in keys if k in your_dict)
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/repls/ForthrightCrushingLaw)

Answer (score 0):

You have a recursive dict, so you will probably need to use recursion. Try this:

```
def get_value(d):
    if 'count' in d and 'size' in d:
        return d['count'], d['size']
    elif 'children' in d:
        return get_value['children']
```

Note this will only return the first element it finds with count and size. You easily can make it check the name. It returns `None` if no leaf nodes are found

Answer (score 0):

We can create some recursion function to search for the `key` as follows:

```
def search_data_key(data, key):
    if key in data:
        yield data[key]
    for k in data:
        if isinstance(data[k], list):
            for i in data[k]:
                for j in search_data_key(i, key):
                    yield j

data = [{'name': 'stack', 'children': [{'name': 'flow', 'children': [{'name': 'lldp', 'children': [{'name': 'sourc', 'children': [{'name': 'lldque.jrc', 'count': '11', 'size': '37'}]}]}, {'name': 'arp', 'children': [{'name': 'src', 'children': [{'name': 'arpred.cec', 'count': '37', 'size': '67'}]}]}]}]}]

print(list(search_data_key(data[0], 'count')))
print(list(search_data_key(data[0], 'size')))

output:

['11', '37']
['37', '67']
```